# Is MongoDB a good fit for this?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In a system I'm building, it's essentially an issue tracking system, but with various issue templates. Some issue types will have different formats that others.

I was originally planning on using MySQL with a main `issues` table and an `issues_meta` table that contains key => value pairs. However, I'm thinking NoSQL (MongoDB) might be the better option.

> Can MongoDB provide me with the ability to generate "standard"
>   reports, like # of issues by type, # of issues by type by month, # of
>   issues assigned per person, etc? I ask this because I've read a few
>   sources that said Mongo was bad at reporting.

---

I'm also planning on storing my audit logs in Mongo, since I want a single "table" for all actions (Modifications to any table). In Mongo I can store each field that was changed easily, since it is schemaless. Is this a bad idea?

Anything else I should know, and will Mongo work for what I want?

Comment: @woz Not anymore I don't... Also, the main question was if NoSQL is capable of providing reporting. I'll restructure my question. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think MongoDB suits to this problem better then others NoSQL? If you're going to store just key-value pairs, then you're losing the main MongoDB benefit (structured documents).

Comment: MongoDB is a database server, so I think what you really want to look into are reporting solutions that support MongoDB as a data source.  For example, [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/big-data/nosql/10gen/) or [Jasper Reports](http://www.jaspersoft.com/bigdata).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think MongoDB will be a perfect match for that use case.

- MongoDB collections are heterogeneous, meaning you can store documents with different fields in the same bag. So different reporting templates won't be a show stopper. You will be able to model a full issue with a single document.
- MongoDB would be a good fit for logging too. You may be interested in capped collections.
- Should you need to have relational association between documents, you can do have it too.
- If you are using Ruby, I can recommend you Mongoid. It will make it easier. Also, it has support for versioning of documents.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB will definitely work (and you can use [capped collections](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections) to automatically drop old records, if you want), but you should ask yourself, does it fit to this task well? For use case you've described it is better option to use [Redis](http://sunilarora.org/another-redis-use-case-centralized-logging) (simple and fast enough) or Riak (if you care a lot about your log data).

Comment: Well I'm not just going to store key => value pairs, I'm going to store the schema directly because I can use different schemas for different issue types. Instead of being forced to use two separate tables, I can use a single collection.